# JIRA JQL filter criteria to display moved projects

Tags: filter, jira, jql

i have a question regarding jira jql filter criterias to move display moved projects.
We have four projects in our JIRA and i want to create a statistic to display processes which are moved from project A to project b.
If i want to build a filter like..
    project = "A" and project changed to "B"
...it says that historical searches are not possible within the "project" field.

Background:
The project "A" is an analysis project and decides if a task goes to the development project (project "B") or not.
So, i want to display how much positive decisions were made from the analysis team.
I hope anyone can help me :).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box solution that is available to achieve this, you will need to have the **[Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner?_ga=2.106385728.2110930018.1541752963-665356806.1508320943)** plugin installed.

Along with the plugin, you might need the following script to be run to identify the issues that are moved from Project **AAA** to **BBB.**

Paste the following into the `Script Runner` console, select `Groovy` as the scripting engine and run this script.

```
package eventim.scripts

import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.search.SearchService
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter

jqlQuery = 'project = BBB'
fromProject = 'AAA'
result = ''

def changeHistoryManager = ComponentAccessor.getChangeHistoryManager()

getFilterResult(jqlQuery,log).each{ Issue issue ->
    oldKeys = changeHistoryManager.getPreviousIssueKeys(issue.id)
    oldKeys.findAll{it==~/$fromProject.*/}.each{
        result += "$it -> ${issue.key}\n"
    }
}

return result

List<Issue> getFilterResult(String jqlSearch, log) {
    def searchService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(SearchService.class);
    def user = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext.getLoggedInUser()
    List<Issue> issues = null

    def parseResult =  searchService.parseQuery(user, jqlSearch);
    if (parseResult.isValid()) {
        def searchResult = searchService.search(user, parseResult.getQuery(), PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter())
        issues = searchResult.issues
    } else {
        log.error("Invalid JQL: " + jqlSearch);
    }
    return issues
}
```

If you seem that this is a tedious process, then you can try out the **[JQL Tricks Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks.jql-plugin?_ga=2.106385728.2110930018.1541752963-665356806.1508320943)**.

You can find more details on this [page](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-find-issues-that-were-moved-from-one-project-to-another/qaq-p/49115). Hope this helps!!!